# Convert jpeg image mat to tiff

Tags: opencv, image-processing, libjpeg

I'm using openCV and libjpeg is there a way to convert jpeg Black&white image to Tiff,
I need to do so without saving the CV::mat to a file?

Thank's

Comment: Have you considered [`imencode`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode)?

Comment: there is a way to convert it back to tiff mat?

Comment: TIFF is a file format, it has nothing to do with `Mat`. That's the same no matter what you do with it - images just get decoded when you `imread` and encoded when you `imwrite` (or `imdecode` and `imencode` from/to memory buffers).

Comment: thanks, what about the convention to tiff from jpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cv::imencode()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) to take a Mat and encode it into a vector of bytes:

```
// bool imencode(const string& ext, InputArray img, vector<uchar>& buf, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>())¶

cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.jpg");
std::vector<uchar> buf;
imencode(".tiff", image, buf);
```

The TIFF encoded result is in buf.